# Should I merge feature branches to my main branch at the end?

Tags: git

My git structure looks like this.

I have one branch called `main` which is the main branch as the name says.

Then I have `main_live` and `main_test` branching out from `main`.

If I develope a new feature, then I always start a new branch from `main`.

First I merge the feature into the branch `main_test` then it is getting tested and after the tests are done I merge this branch into `main_live`.

But what should I do with the feature branch at the end? Should I delete it, merge it with `main` or just leave it open?

Comment: When you merge "feature" branch into "main_test", is that not already the end of "feature" branch?

Comment: No, I still have to merge it into the branch `main_live`, so I still need it

Comment: I am usually merge  main_test into main_live after the tests are done

Comment: @GovindParashar, then I would have to wait till all feature branches in  `main_test` branch are completly tested until I can bring the feature live, this would be stupid.

Comment: @Black : main_live is your production candidate right. Once you done all the testing then I have to merge. If you are maintaining live tags then you can merge. I think it is unnecessary extra process.

Comment: @GovindParashar, you don't seem to understand. There are multiple feature branches in `main_test` if a feature was successfully tested then it has to go live immediately. How should I be able to bring it live if the others branches are not tested yet if I would do It like you and only merge `main_test` in to live?! Impossible